# convertir consulta SQL a Linq con entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Estoy iniciando con linq y queria pasar esta consulta que hice en SQL a codigo linq

```
SELECT DISTINT det.idcampo 
from tablaA det
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT pla.idcampo FROM tablaB pla where det.idcampo= pla.idcampo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = (from det in tablaA where !tablab.Where(s=>s.idcampo == det.idcampo).Select(p=> p.idcampo).Contains(det.idcampo) select det.idcampo).Distinct();
```

Probaría con algo así